# Unmarshalling Self Closed Tag with Empty Nested List

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I can't see to properly annotate my classes such that a self-closed tag causes the class to create an empty list.  In order words, the list isn't specified in the XML at all.

For my question I'll refer to the following two example classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="a")
public class A {
    @XmlElement
    List<B> bs;
}

@XmlRootElement(name="b")
public class B {
    @XmlValue
    String v;
}
```

This XML unmarshals fine:

```
<a>
    <b>One</b>
    <b>Two</b>
    <b>Three</b>
</a>
```

This second XML example also unmarshals correctly with the intended empty list:

```
<a>
    <b/>
</a>
```

However, the third example causes the XML to not unmarshal at all.

```
<a/>
```

The behavior I'd like to see when unmarshaling the third example is identical to the second where the class gets initialized with an empty list.  Is this possible using JAXB, or am I trying to do something that flies in the face of the defined behavior?

Comment: *not unmarshal at all* - in which sense? You don't get an exception, do you?

Comment: No JAXBException is thrown.  When A is a field then that field gets set to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard approach (also used by JAXB when generating code from an XML schema) is

```
@XmlRootElement(name="a")
public class A {
    private List<B> bs;

    @XmlElement(name="b")
    public List<B> getBs(){
        if( bs == null ){
            bs = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return bs;
    }
}
```

No setter for bs!

Comment: This worked as advertised.  Just make sure to initialize the List explicitly or you'll get a NullPointException on unmarshal.

Comment: How can there be a NPE? JAXB doesn't access a private field if there's a getter.